# Dragon Naturally Speaking fails on WPF sub menus

Tags: wpf, menu, accessibility, ui-automation, voice-recognition

My WPF application menus fail to work with Dragon Natually Speaking, and hence I assume other screen readers and accessibility software. I want my software to work well for my blind and disabled customers.
 In order to figure out my mistake I also tried other WPF applications like Visual Studio 2010, and Expression Blend 4, but they have the SAME BUG. In all cases I can use voice to drop down a Main Menu HEADER like "File", "Edit", "Help" - BUT can NEVER activate the child menu items like "New", "Open", or "Close".
 I've read all I can on Accesibility and "UI Automation", I've tried running "UI Accessibility Checker" and 'Snoop', these applications also seem to enumerate my Menu HEADERS OK, but not the items on those menus. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most blind users do not use Dragon naturally speaking. If you want to test your application for accessibility by blind users take a look at [NVDA](http://www.nvda-project.org/) This is an open source screen reader you can use to test your applications. If you wish to do additional testing you can look at [Jaws for Windows](http://www.freedomscientific.com/products/fs/jaws-product-page.asp) This is an expensive screen reader, but is generally the one used in the work place by blind individuals at least in the U.S. It sounds like you may be dealing with a bug in Dragon but I don't know enough about the details of windows accessibility API's to give you any more info.

Comment: Thanks guys! I believe the issue to be a bug/limitation of Dragon Natually Speaking. Thanks for the link to NVDA, and Jaws, I'll investigate those.

Answer (score 0):

From your own description/admission it's a bug in Dragon Naturally Speaking - you'd best contact their support department.

Comment: Thanks, It may be that Dragon 10 doesn't support WPF. The new version 11 most likely does. Unfortunatly Nuance's support site throws up SQL errors when I attempt to use it!

Answer (score 0):

My gues is:
you can have, possibly, a similar issue to one we had recently. We had crashes of automatic test software, coused by UI Automation used internally. 
My tip: compare xaml for menu headers and child items and simplify it. In our case it was Labels's Target that caused problems.

```
<Label Target="{Binding ElementName=someOtherControl}" ... />
```

Answer (score 0):

I worked on a WPF application that had to pass really strict accessibility testing.
The tool we used was Jaws and we did not find this kind of issues with menus.
I also cannot imagine Visual Studio and Blend shipping with such a bug.